# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while the object exists

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a music sequencer with a standard piano roll type UI.
It was working well until I made some changes in the model side but it suddenly started to report EXC_BAD_ACCESS at (seemingly) unrelated part.

What's strange is all the necessary variables have their values properly and actually I can print values with po.
In my understanding, EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens when an object doesn't exist, so this seems quite strange.

My question is:

- Is it common to EXC_BAD_ACCESS even the values are there?
- If that's the case what is the possible situation to cause that?

Any suggestion is helpful. Thanks

[Below are the codes]

In my subclass of UICollectionViewLayout:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    // note cells
    let cv = self.collectionView as! YMPianoRollCollectionView;
    let pianoRoll = cv.pianoRollViewController;

    // Call the below func to get the indexes of the Note Objects included in the specified rect
    let indexArray: Array<Int> = pianoRoll!.getNoteIndexes(inRect:rect, useOnlyStartTime: false);

    var retArray : [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

    for i in indexArray {
        if let _ = pianoRoll?.pattern.eventSequence[i] as? YMPatternEventNoteOn {
            retArray.append( self.layoutAttributesForPatternEventInfo(i) )
        }
    }        
    return retArray
}
```

In my "piano roll" class which contains UICollectionView

```
func getNoteIndexes(inRect rect:CGRect, useOnlyStartTime: Bool) -> Array<Int>  {
    //
    // Transform given values into musical values
    //
    let musicRange :YMMusicalValueRange = screenInfo.getMusicalRange(rect);        
    let startTime = musicRange.origin.time;
    let endTime = musicRange.origin.time + musicRange.size.timeLength;        
    let lowNoteU = musicRange.origin.noteNumber;
    let highNoteU = musicRange.origin.noteNumber + musicRange.size.numberOfNotes;

    var retArray : [Int] = []
    for i in 0..<pattern.eventSequence.count {
        if let e = pattern.eventSequence[i] as? YMPatternEventNoteOn {
            //
            // Prepare ranges
            //
            let noteNo = e.noteNo; //<- App Crashes Here with BAD_ACCESS
            let noteStTime = e.time;
            let noteEnTime = e.time + e.duration;

            let targetNoteRange = Range<Int>(uncheckedBounds: (lowNoteU, highNoteU));

            let targetTimeRange = Range<Int64>(uncheckedBounds: (startTime, endTime))
            let noteTimeRange = Range<Int64>(uncheckedBounds: (noteStTime, noteEnTime))

            //
            // Check the match
            //
            let noteMatches = targetNoteRange.contains(noteNo);
            let timeMatches = useOnlyStartTime ? targetTimeRange.contains(noteStTime)
                                               : targetTimeRange.overlaps(noteTimeRange)
            if noteMatches && timeMatches {
                retArray.append( i );
                NSLog("XXX Found: note \(noteNo) at \(e.time)");
            }
        }
    }
    return retArray;
}
```

`Error`:- The object states when it crashed

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's the YMPatternEventNoteOn declaration

```
class YMPatternEvent : Codable, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  var time : YMSequenceTime = 0
  // Some utility funcs follow
  // ...
}

class YMPatternEventNoteOn : YMPatternEvent {
  var noteNo : Int = 64
  var velocity : Int = 127
  var duration : YMSequenceTime = 480

  var tempBendId : Int = 0;
  var tempVibratoId : Int = 0;
  var tempArpeggioId : Int = 0;

  convenience init(time :YMSequenceTime, noteNo : Int, velocity: Int, duration: YMSequenceTime) {
    self.init();
    self.time = time;
    self.noteNo = noteNo;
    self.velocity = velocity;
    self.duration = duration;
  }
  // Other methods follow
  // ...

}
```

EDIT2

Note event is created by the user's action

```
//
// In YMPattern object
//
func insertNote(time:YMSequenceTime, noteNo:Int, velocity:Int, duration:YMSequenceTime) -> Int
{
    let onEvent = YMPatternEventNoteOn(time: time, noteNo: noteNo, velocity: velocity, duration: duration);
    let retIndex = insertEvent(onEvent);

    return retIndex;
}

func insertEvent(_ event: YMPatternEvent) -> Int {
    let atTime = event.time;

    var retIndex : Int = 0;
    if(eventSequence.count<1){
        // If it's the first event just add it
        eventSequence.append(event);
        retIndex = 0;
    } else {
        // If any event already exists, insert with time order in consideration
        var i : Int = 0;
        while( atTime > eventSequence[i].time ){
            i += 1;
            if( i >= eventSequence.count ){
                break;
            }
        }
        retIndex = i;
        eventSequence.insert(event, at: i)
    }
 }

//
// In pianoroll view controller
//
func actionButtonReleased(afterDragging: Bool) {
    let values:YMMusicalValuePoint = screenInfo.getMusicalPosition(cursorPosition);        

    // insert new event with default velocity and duration
    let _ = pattern.insertNote(time: values.time, noteNo: values.noteNumber, velocity: 127, duration: screenInfo.timeTicsPerDivision());

    collectionView.reloadData();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151771/discussion-on-question-by-takeshi-yokemura-getting-exc-bad-access-while-the-obje).

Comment: I am having this issue

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it in a way.

By setting the optimization level to "Whole Module Optimization" it stopped reporting the error.

I don't know what is happening internally but if someone is having the same issue, this might work as a quick fix.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I had a similar issue, by making a class conform to protocol Encodable, E_BAD_ACCESS at runtime but debugger could show the right class type and content. Enabling "Whole Module Optimization" for debug compilation (as it is for release) "solves" the problem...